# simple SQL query to display values from a table based on condition

Tags: mysql

### Assume there is client and a server

**`Client::`** Android mobile

**`Server::`** AWS server

Server has `mysql` database installed in it

**`Database name::`** Person

**`Tables in person Database::`** "sam" and "carl"

***Now mobile sends a request...***

- How to write an `SQL query` so that if mobile sends request i/p as
  "sam" `display all the values of sam table`
- But if the mobile sends an i/p as carl  then dipslay all the values
  of carl table

[Note]
I have used statement `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`

What i am trying to achieve is a condition response when a client request comes in

---

**I/p means ::** say i get carl as ip .... i want to perform one query else sam as input ... i want to perform another query

what query statement should i need to write ?

---

*hope i am stating my problem correctly*

**Thanks**

Comment: remove the sql-server tag if this is mysql

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME where PersonName like('Carl%')` - using the wildcard `%` for names that start with 'Carl' i.e. Carlos

Comment: What does "i/p" mean exactly?

Comment: I/p means :: say i get carl as ip .... i want to perform one query else sam as input ... i want to perform another query

Comment: Are carl and sam has the same field structure?

Comment: Yes they have same field structure !, both tables are in same database also !

Comment: This looks like poor design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to get the IP address of the Android client in your server code. In PHP ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)):

```
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Or, if you have multiple Apache web servers behind ELB ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119739/determine-ip-address-of-client-behind-amazon-elb)):

```
$http_headers = apache_request_headers(); 
$client_ip = $http_headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
```

Now your PHP code can choose which query to run according to the value of `$client_ip`. If the address is Sam's, run `select * from sam`, if it is Carl's, run `select * from carl`. If it's an unknown IP address, then you can respond with an error message.

Anyway, I don't think IP-based identification is a good idea. If Carl or Sam reboots his Android phone, its IP address will change, and the connection will no longer work.

There are problems with your database design, too. For example, if your current Sam and Carl tables contain chat messages, then the following schema would be better:

```
- User table: ID, Name, IPAddress 
- Message table: ID, UserID, SendingTime, Text
```

For these tables, the query which lists the messages of the current user would look like this:

```
SELECT User.Name, Message.SendingTime, Message.Text
FROM User, Message
WHERE User.ID = Message.UserID AND User.IPAddress = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

Here `'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'` would be the value of `$client_ip`.

Answer (score 0):

For this u have to require one more table where you store IP address and their table name and create query like this

```
Select tableName from IPTable where ip= 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

and using that table name in your second query

```
select * from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for your i/p ..... but can you update your answer on merging those two queries into single query if its possible technically !

Comment: as far i know it's not possible, Please mark answer for help to some one else.